# Qt How to Filter keyPressEvent with Autorepeat

Tags: qt, events, keypress, eventfilter, autorepeat

I'm trying to filter key press/release events so that I can setup timers for long press events for my application (e.g. pop up a menu when the down error is held for 3 seconds). I'm having some trouble with some inconsistency from autorepeat of QKeyEvent though. Here is my code:

```
Mainview::Mainview (QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow (parent)
{
    setupUi (this);
    qApp->installEventFilter(this); // event filter for key presses
    ...
}

void Mainview::ControlsPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if ((event->isAutoRepeat()))
    {
        return;
    }

    QString s = QString("Key PRESS event: %1.").arg(event->text());
    qDebug() << s;
}

void Mainview::ControlsReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if ((event->isAutoRepeat()))
    {
        return;
    }

    QString s = QString("Key RELEASE event: %1.").arg(event->text());
    qDebug() << s;
}

bool Mainview::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        qDebug() << event << " | " << obj;
        /* Only grab the key event from the parent window object */
        if (obj->objectName() == "MainviewClassWindow")
        {
            this->ControlsPressEvent(dynamic_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event));
            return true;
        }
    }
    else if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyRelease)
    {
        qDebug() << event << " | " << obj;
        /* Only grab the key event from the parent window object */
        if (obj->objectName() == "MainviewClassWindow")
        {
            this->ControlsReleaseEvent(dynamic_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event));
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't:

Here is qDebug output in a working example where I press the key once, hold, and release:

```
"Key PRESS event: ."
QKeyEvent(KeyRelease, Key_Down, autorepeat, count=1)  |  QWidgetWindow(0xa522a0, name = "MainviewClassWindow")
QKeyEvent(KeyPress, Key_Down, autorepeat, count=1)  |  QWidgetWindow(0xa522a0, name = "MainviewClassWindow")
QKeyEvent(KeyRelease, Key_Down, autorepeat, count=1)  |  QWidgetWindow(0xa522a0, name = "MainviewClassWindow")
QKeyEvent(KeyPress, Key_Down, autorepeat, count=1)  |  QWidgetWindow(0xa522a0, name = "MainviewClassWindow")
QKeyEvent(KeyRelease, Key_Down, autorepeat, count=1)  |  QWidgetWindow(0xa522a0, name = "MainviewClassWindow")
QKeyEvent(KeyPress, Key_Down, autorepeat, count=1)  |  QWidgetWindow(0xa522a0, name = "MainviewClassWindow")
"Key RELEASE event: ."
```

Here is qDebug output in a non-working example where I press the key once, hold, and release:

```
QKeyEvent(KeyPress, Key_Down)  |  QWidgetWindow(0xa522a0, name = "MainviewClassWindow")
"Key PRESS event: ."
QKeyEvent(KeyRelease, Key_Down)  |  QWidgetWindow(0xa522a0, name = "MainviewClassWindow")
"Key RELEASE event: ."
QKeyEvent(KeyPress, Key_Down)  |  QWidgetWindow(0xa522a0, name = "MainviewClassWindow")
"Key PRESS event: ."
QKeyEvent(KeyRelease, Key_Down)  |  QWidgetWindow(0xa522a0, name = "MainviewClassWindow")
"Key RELEASE event: ."
QKeyEvent(KeyPress, Key_Down)  |  QWidgetWindow(0xa522a0, name = "MainviewClassWindow")
"Key PRESS event: ."
QKeyEvent(KeyRelease, Key_Down)  |  QWidgetWindow(0xa522a0, name = "MainviewClassWindow")
"Key RELEASE event: ."
QKeyEvent(KeyPress, Key_Down)  |  QWidgetWindow(0xa522a0, name = "MainviewClassWindow")
"Key PRESS event: ."
QKeyEvent(KeyRelease, Key_Down)  |  QWidgetWindow(0xa522a0, name = "MainviewClassWindow")
"Key RELEASE event: ."
```

Why is the `autorepeat` member of QKeyEvent inconsistent in being set? Maybe this is the incorrect approach to key press, hold, and release processing?

Thanks

Comment: What *specific* keys are you pressing and releasing in each case? What platform are you testing on, and with which version of qt?

Comment: The examples above I am using the down arrow keys, but I have tested and get the same results with any letters as well. I am running in Ubuntu 16.04 with Qt 5.10.0.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem (archlinux, qt-5.10.0). Please provide a [mcve].